# Where does an "ASP.NET Web Application" project store user registration details?

Tags: asp.net

When developing a website using a Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Web Application template, where does the user's information get stored when they register their details through the register.cshtml view page?

Comment: it stores in LocalDB

Comment: Thanks Alex. Where would I find the LocalDB? I've spent hours trying to find out where the registered information goes when it's submitted but I've had no success.

Answer (score 2):

You create an MVC Web Application in VS 2013. At this moment, the database doesn't exist. But when you run the application on localhost and register a user, the database is created.

To find its name, look in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20150615111350.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20150615111350;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

To find its location, look in the App_Data folder:

[image: localdb]

You can use also SQL Server Management Studio for managing this database.

Comment: Readers should note that this is good general advice. Database access almost always starts with a connection string stored in the web.config. You can start there to see what kind of database is being used and how one connects to it.

Comment: One trick that might work (it worked once for me). In Solution Explorer, turn on "Show All Files". Then expand the App_Data folder and you'll see the above files. Double-click the .mdf file and it will be added to Server Explorer under Data Connections. Awkward.